# Thread and Task in C# do not execute independently

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I am executing a thread and a task. 
**ReceiveThread** is a **thread** that continuously receives data from the network, and **WriteTask** is **task** that writes the data that ReceiveThread receives, into a buffer. They are in separate threads because I should still be able to receive high speed data and store them in a buffer, while the writer, which is slower, would only fetch from the buffer at an interval.

ReceiveThread and WriteTask share a common buffer, which uses ReaderWriterLockSlim to avoid read and write access errors. It just happened that I created ReceiveThread first before WriteTask, but I should be making them of the same type soon. I just noticed that when I put a break at WriteTask, ReceiveThread pauses too, which I did not expect to happen, because I am expecting them to be separate threads/task.

I'm wondering if being a thread and a task is factor for not treating the two as separate tasks.

This is not the whole source code, but somehow the idea is like this.

```
if (_receiveThread == null)
{
    _receiveThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReceiveLoop));
    _receiveThread.Start();
}
if (_writeTask == null)
{
    _writeTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(WriteLoop);
}

private void ReceiveLoop()
{
     while (true)
     {
         data = ReceiveData();
         _rwLock.EnterReadLock();
         _buffer.Add(data)
         _rwLock.ExitReadLock();
     }
}

private void WriteLoop()
{
     while (true)
     {
         _rwLock.EnterWriteLock();
         WriteToFile(_buffer);
         _rwLock.ExitWriteLock();
     }
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about a breakpoint in the debugger? If that's the case, the debugger will pause and resume all threads during stepping.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen Yes, I am talking about the debugger. Ok, looks like it's a debugging foundation that I missed. If that is the case, then I am going to test the program without break points. Thanks. :)

Comment: You might also be interested in my [ProducerConsumerStream](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=852), which formalizes this kind of thing.